# FFmpeg is using more threads than I expect when using -threads

Tags: ffmpeg

The number of actual threads used by FFmpeg do not line up with the number I pass using the `-threads` argument.

I've run tests on both my MacBook Air, which has 4 cores, and a VM I have which has 2 cores. The number of threads used are consistent across both machines.

Using a single thread returns what I would expect: 1 thread is used.

```
$ ffmpeg -threads 1 -i clip.mp4 -threads 1 -acodec libfdk_aac -vcodec libx264 -b:v 200k -vf scale=200:-2 -y clip-200.mp4

$ cat /proc/$(pgrep ffmpeg)/status | grep Threads
Threads:        1
```

If I set the `-threads` option on the input, it increase the number of threads used to 3. This somewhat makes sense to me since the input would use 2 threads and the output would use a single thread.

```
$ ffmpeg -threads 2 -i clip.mp4 -threads 1 -acodec libfdk_aac -vcodec libx264 -b:v 200k -vf scale=200:-2 -y clip-200.mp4

$ cat /proc/$(pgrep ffmpeg)/status | grep Threads
Threads:        3
```

This is where I start to get confused. If instead, I leave the input `-threads` at 1 and set the output `-threads` to 2, it uses 8 threads (not 3 like I would expect).

```
$ ffmpeg -threads 1 -i clip.mp4 -threads 2 -acodec libfdk_aac -vcodec libx264 -b:v 200k -vf scale=200:-2 -y clip-200.mp4

cat /proc/$(pgrep ffmpeg)/status | grep Threads
Threads:        8
```

If I add a second output with `-threads 1`, it does not increase the number of threads used.

```
$ ffmpeg -threads 1 -i clip.mp4 -threads 2 -acodec libfdk_aac -vcodec libx264 -b:v 200k -vf scale=200:-2 -y clip-200.mp4 \
                                -threads 1 -acodec libfdk_aac -vcodec libx264 -b:v 250k -vf scale=250:-2 -y clip-250.mp4

cat /proc/$(pgrep ffmpeg)/status | grep Threads
Threads:        8
```

However, if the second output also specifies two threads, the thread count jumps to 15.

```
$ ffmpeg -threads 1 -i clip.mp4 -threads 2 -acodec libfdk_aac -vcodec libx264 -b:v 200k -vf scale=200:-2 -y clip-200.mp4 \
                                -threads 2 -acodec libfdk_aac -vcodec libx264 -b:v 250k -vf scale=250:-2 -y clip-250.mp4

cat /proc/$(pgrep ffmpeg)/status | grep Threads
Threads:        15
```

Every incremental bump beyond `-threads 2` will use an additional 3 threads (e.g. `threads 2` uses 8, `threads 3` uses 11, `threads 4` uses 14.

So it seems like anytime you use `-threads 2` the formula is something like:

```
1 + [ (1 + (3 * output_n_threads)) + ... ]
```

Ultimately my question is why do the number of actual threads used wildly differ from the options I'm specifying.

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Short answer - these options don't exactly do that you think.

Long answer follows:

FFmpeg always has one main thread which does most of the processing. In case of multiple inputs there are also input threads for demuxing (1 thread per input); for single input demuxing is done on main thread.

Setting "threads N" (where N > 1) on input enables multithreaded decoding which can spawn N additional threads for each decoder which supports it. In your case video decoder supports it and audio decoder doesn't so it is 3 threads - 1 main thread + 2 threads for video decoding.

Similarly, setting "threads N" on output enables multithreaded filtering and encoding which can spawn N additional threads for each filtergraph (I think in older ffmpeg versions this was "up to N threads per each filter") and each encoder which supports it. There is also one important caveat - this only applies to encoders which do their thread management via ffmpeg; libx264 doesn't do that - it forwards requested thread count to the x264 library which does its own thread management. x264 then might create up to 2*N threads (exact number depends on many encoding parameters). So for "threads 2" with single output you'll get 1 main thread + 2 threads for the scaler + at least 2 threads for libx264. This still doesn't add up to `num_outputs * (1 + num_threads)` behaviour you are seeing and I'd be interested to learn where additional threads come from but hopefully my answer explains why "threads 2" option doesn't increase thread count by 2.